ROS2 node auto launch booting
I would like to launch my ROS2 nodes right after boot my PC. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and humble now. As far as i know, I have to make '.service' file in /etc/systemd/system to auto launch my node.
This is my service file
[Unit]
Description=Ros2 launch
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/launch.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
RequiredBy=multi-user.target

and this is shell script file that i want to execute (launch.sh)
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash 
source /home/robot/robot_ws/install/setup.bash 
source /home/robot/ydlidar_ros2_driver/install/setup.bash 
ros2 launch /home/robot/ydlidar_ros2_driver/launch/ydlidar_launch.py
echo "hello"

I changed permission of my service file and shell script as 777 also, but still didn't work. Error is like follow
○ launching.service - Ros2 launch
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/launching.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2024-04-12 19:17:38 KST; 18s ago
    Process: 26374 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/launch.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 26374 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1.288s

Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]: This error state is being overwritten:
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]:   'rcutils_expand_user failed, at ./src/logging_dir.c:81'
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]: with this new error message:
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]:   'Failed to get logging directory, at ./src/rcl_logging_spdlog.cpp:83'
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]: rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]: <<<
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26459]: [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): failed to initialize logging: Failed to get logging directory, at ./src/rcl_logging_spdlog.cpp:83
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot launch.sh[26374]: hello
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot systemd[1]: launching.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 12 19:17:38 robot systemd[1]: launching.service: Consumed 1.288s CPU time.
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-17/17 (END)

First question is is there any part that i miss something. I really have no idea and if there is any other way can start node automatically right after boot the PC please I really need your help
If i change shell script (launch.sh) only small part '&'
#!/bin/bash
    
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash 
source /home/robot/robot_ws/install/setup.bash &
source /home/robot/ydlidar_ros2_driver/install/setup.bash &
ros2 launch /home/robot/ydlidar_ros2_driver/launch/ydlidar_launch.py
echo "hello"

result is follow.
○ launching.service

 - Ros2 launch
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/launching.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2024-04-12 19:28:25 KST; 1s ago
    Process: 26885 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/launch.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 26885 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1.261s

Apr 12 19:28:24 robot systemd[1]: Started Ros2 launch.
Apr 12 19:28:25 robot launch.sh[26931]: [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-04-12-19-28-25-111127-robot-26931
Apr 12 19:28:25 robot launch.sh[26931]: [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Apr 12 19:28:25 robot launch.sh[26931]: [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: "package 'ydlidar_ros2_driver' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/humble']"
Apr 12 19:28:25 robot launch.sh[26885]: hello
Apr 12 19:28:25 robot systemd[1]: launching.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 12 19:28:25 robot systemd[1]: launching.service: Consumed 1.261s CPU time.
lines 1-14/14 (END)

second question is why both show different result
Thank you for read my question. If there is anything that I didn't follow the rule of community please tell me. I will fix it right away

For your first issue, it seems from wherever you launch, the logging directory is inaccessible, try
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser

For your second question, & will suspend the process into the background, so what happens is, sourceing of your workspace is not finished when you invoke your launch file, hence resources cannot be found and you get this error that a resource is not found. So, let all your sourceing finish (without &), but any lasting processes (like a launch) send to background to proceed with your script (with &), then you should also see the echo "hello" being printed.

Hi, I tried
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser
but still show same message. Did I missed something?

Mhm.. I still suspect your environment is not setup properly. Have you seen this post from 2019.
